# Versioning with NPanday and Maven Release Plugin

Tags: .net, maven-release-plugin

I'm working on a C# .NET webservices project that uses Maven with NPanday. We also want to use the release plugin, but I've found a minor versioning issue.

NPanday will (conveniently) update the `AssemblyInfo.cs` file with the version number from the POM file when you do a build, but it doesn't commit to that change to SVN (nor would I necessarily want it to).

The release plugin doesn't know about `AssemblyInfo.cs` (nor would I expect it to). But this means that my AssemblyInfo.cs and POM versions get out of sync during release operations.

For example, say I do `mvn release:branch` to create a 2.0.x branch from trunk. The POM and `AssemblyInfo.cs` were probably both at 2.0.0-SNAPSHOT in the trunk prior to branching, so the branch looks as I would expect. But in the updated trunk, the POM version has been updated (e.g. 2.1.0-SNAPSHOT) but the AssemblyInfo.cs is still at 2.0.0-SNAPSHOT.

This isn't a huge problem because the next `mvn compile` on the trunk will update the `AssemblyInfo.cs` and someone will commit it. But it's worse with `release:prepare` because the tag created from the branch has the correct version in the POM (e.g. 2.0.0), but the `AssemblyInfo.cs` still says -SNAPSHOT. When release:perform is run, NPanday will update the `AssemblyInfo.cs` file, but then there's a floating modification from that tag.

Does anyone know of a way to rectify this with the release plugin? I could certainly create correct branches/tags by hand or code up a custom tool. Or I could just leave it as is, saying that "The AssemblyInfo.cs file isn't the definitive version source, the POM is." But I'd prefer the best of both worlds.

Comment: Good question! I'll keep that in mind! I'm currently building a showcase for Maven Release + NPanday. As soon as I have solved the issue there, I'll be back with an answer.

Find the showcase here: https://github.com/lcorneliussen/NpShowcase

Answer (score 0):

I'd let NPanday generate the AssemblyInfo.cs for you - then you avoid checking in things with versions in it...

Visual Studio will work fine without assembly infos... Version is 0.0.0.0, then :-) - I'm doing it that way.

Actually NPanday is "breaking" the maven rules - a build should never fiddle with the original files, but rather just update things in /target...